How do I get all my variants from the API? The query only gives me 250 and not the 1300
How do I get all my API variants? The query only gives me 250 and not all 1300.
I have a problem with my code in AL for Business Central. What I am trying to do is to get from the shopify API all my variants that are a total of 1300 and insert them into a table created in Business Central.
When I run the code if you do the first query to the API and brings me only 50 variants which is what by default limits the API itself.
I tried doing the pagination but I was unsuccessful, I get the following status 0 error:
Status error 0
My code is as follows:
procedure InsertVariants()
var
    Client: HttpClient;
    Request: HttpRequestMessage;
    Response: HttpResponseMessage;
    Content: HttpContent;
    JsonResponse: Text;
    JsonObject: JsonObject;
    JsonArray: JsonArray;
    JsonToken: JsonToken;
    VariantObject: JsonObject;
    TempToken: JsonToken;
    AccessToken: Text;
    Url: Text;
    ShopifyVariantRecord: Record "Shopify Variants Mercalab";
    VariantIdText: Text;
    VariantIdInteger: BigInteger;
    ProductIdText: Text;
    ProductIdInteger: BigInteger;
    PriceText: Text;
    PriceDecimal: Decimal;
    CompareAtPriceText: Text;
    CompareAtPriceDecimal: Decimal;
    Sku: Text;
    Price: Decimal;
    CompareAtPrice: Decimal;
    CompareAtPriceBoolean: Boolean;
    ShopifyVariantesOriginal: Record "Shpfy Variant";
    NextPageUrl: Text;
    BaseUrl: Text;
    Shopify : Record "Shpfy Company";
begin
    ShopifyVariantRecord.DeleteAll();
    BaseUrl := 'https://shoptest.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-04/variants.json';
    NextPageUrl := BaseUrl;

    repeat
        Request.SetRequestUri(NextPageUrl);
        Request.Method := 'GET';
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add('X-Shopify-Access-Token', Shopify.Token);

        if Client.Send(Request, Response) then begin
            Content := Response.Content();
            Content.ReadAs(JsonResponse);
            JsonObject.ReadFrom(JsonResponse);
            if JsonObject.Get('variants', JsonToken) then begin
                JsonArray := JsonToken.AsArray();
                foreach JsonToken in JsonArray do begin
                    if JsonToken.IsObject() then begin
                        VariantObject := JsonToken.AsObject();

                        VariantObject.Get('id', TempToken);
                        VariantIdText := TempToken.AsValue().AsText();
                        EVALUATE(VariantIdInteger, VariantIdText);
                        if VariantIdInteger < 0 then
                            VariantIdInteger := 0;

                        VariantObject.Get('product_id', TempToken);
                        ProductIdText := TempToken.AsValue().AsText();
                        EVALUATE(ProductIdInteger, ProductIdText);
                        if ProductIdInteger < 0 then
                            ProductIdInteger := 0;

                        VariantObject.Get('price', TempToken);
                        PriceText := TempToken.AsValue().AsText();
                        EVALUATE(PriceDecimal, PriceText);
                        if PriceDecimal < 0 then
                            PriceDecimal := 0;

                        VariantObject.Get('compare_at_price', TempToken);
                        CompareAtPriceBoolean := TempToken.AsValue().IsNull();
                        if CompareAtPriceBoolean then
                            CompareAtPriceDecimal := 0
                        else begin
                            CompareAtPriceText := TempToken.AsValue().AsText();
                            EVALUATE(CompareAtPriceDecimal, CompareAtPriceText);
                            if CompareAtPriceDecimal < 0 then
                                CompareAtPriceDecimal := 0;
                        end;

                        VariantObject.Get('sku', TempToken);
                        Sku := TempToken.AsValue().AsText();
                        ShopifyVariantesOriginal.SetRange(SKU, Sku);
                        if ShopifyVariantesOriginal.FindSet() then begin
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.Init();
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.id := VariantIdInteger;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.product_id := ProductIdInteger;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.price := PriceDecimal;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.compare_at_price := CompareAtPriceDecimal;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.sku := Sku;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.Coincide := (VariantIdInteger = ShopifyVariantesOriginal.Id);
                            ShopifyVariantRecord."Id variante BC" := ShopifyVariantesOriginal.Id;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.Insert();
                        end else begin
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.Init();
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.id := VariantIdInteger;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.product_id := ProductIdInteger;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.price := PriceDecimal;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.compare_at_price := CompareAtPriceDecimal;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.sku := Sku;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.Coincide := (VariantIdInteger = ShopifyVariantesOriginal.Id);
                            ShopifyVariantRecord."Id variante BC" := ShopifyVariantesOriginal.Id;
                            ShopifyVariantRecord.Insert();
                        end;
                    end;
                end;

                NextPageUrl := GetNextPageUrl(Response);
            end else
                Message('No variants were found in the response.');
        end else begin
            Message('Error when querying Shopify API: %1', Format(Response.HttpStatusCode));
            NextPageUrl := '';
        end;
    until NextPageUrl = '';
    Message('%1 Shopify variants were saved.', ShopifyVariantRecord.Count());
end;

procedure GetNextPageUrl(Response: HttpResponseMessage): Text
var
    LinkHeader: List of [Text];
    LinkParts: List of [Text];
    LinkPart: Text;
begin
    if Response.Headers.Contains('Link') then begin
        Response.Headers.GetValues('Link', LinkHeader);
        foreach LinkPart in LinkHeader do begin
            LinkParts := LinkPart.Split(',');
            foreach LinkPart in LinkParts do begin
                if LinkPart.Contains('rel="next"') then begin
                    exit(LinkPart.Substring(LinkPart.IndexOf('<') + 1, LinkPart.IndexOf('>') - LinkPart.IndexOf('<') - 1));
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    exit('');
end;


This is the default behavior when querying productVariants from shopify. The api is designed to give you maximum of 250 variants list in each batch.
You can use fragments and cursor-based pagination to get all of the variants. Using this you will need to make 6 individual requests to fetch all of the 1300 variants.
